# why is my document readyState always jump to complete

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, vuejs2

I want to add loading screen when document readyState is interactive, but the loading state wont appear.

When i try to console log the document readyState on my Vue App, it's always returned complete. Anyone can help me?

```
 created() {
    document.addEventListener("readystatechange", (e) => console.log(e.target.readyState))
  },
```

Console on chrome
[image: console on chrome]

Comment: By the time your Vue component's `created()` method runs, the document has well and truly finished loading

Comment: i have tried on beforecreate() but that still return the same value, so how can i implement the loading state? please answer if you know

Comment: This won't be something you can do within a Vue component. You'd need to attach event listeners much earlier such as in a separate `.js` file you include in your HTML `<head>`